# Some frames are missing part of a surface in Maple $\texttt{implicitplot3d}$ animation

Tags: maple

I want to create an animation of a surface when some parameter is changing, using for loop in maple to create a sequence of frames and they display them as sequence of plots. I was able to obtain an animation, however some of the frames are missing their middle portion. For example these are the i=11th and i=12th frames:

[image]

[image]

One can see that 11th frame has a cut in the middle. Here is the animation[image]

Since the surface on some of the frames is cut, the middle portion of the surface dissappears and then appears again.

> Q: How to make this animation smooth so that the whole surface appears on each frame of the animation?

I attach the maple code I used to create the animation:

```
with(plots);
r := 'r';
theta := 'theta';
z := 'z';
for i from 0 to 50 do
    p || i := plots[implicitplot3d](abs(z) = EllipticE(sqrt(1-r^2/(1+(1/50)*i)), sqrt(1+(1/50)*i)), r = sqrt((1/50)*i) .. sqrt(1+(1/50)*i), theta = 0 .. 2*Pi, z = -1 .. 1, coords = cylindrical, numpoints = 1600)
end do;
plots[display](p || (0 .. 50), insequence = true);
```

Increasing numpoints doesn't solve the problem. In the displayed animation the value `numpoints=16000` has been used.

Comment: I would venture to guess that this is a consequence of a rounding that occurs near a critical value of the argument function used by $\texttt{implicitplot3d}$: For some values of the time parameter, it simply doesn't find the intermediate solutions.

Comment: @Travis that was my initial guess too, so I plotted using a different command without implicitplot3d:     addcoords(z_cylindrical, [z, r, theta], [r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta), z]); with(plots); r := 'r'; theta := 'theta'; z := 'z'; for i from 0 to 50 do p || i := plot3d(EllipticE(sqrt(1-r^2/(1+(1/50)*i)), sqrt(1+(1/50)*i)), r = sqrt((1/50)*i) .. sqrt(1+(1/50)*i), theta = 0 .. 2*Pi, coords = z_cylindrical, numpoints = 5000) end do; plots[display](p || (0 .. 50), insequence = true);        but still faced the same problem.

Comment: I tried executing the latter code (on Maple 17), but it generated this error for every frame: http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/errors/view.aspx?path=Warning,%20unable%20to%20evaluate%20the%20function%20to%20numeric%20values%20in%20the%20region%3B%20see%20the%20plotting%20command%27s%20help%20page%20to%20ensure%20the%20calling%20sequence%20is%20correct

Comment: (That said, the original code in the question produces different and even more pathological results for me than it did for you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roundoff error introduces imaginary artefacts near the boundary. One simple solution for this example is to wrap with the `Re` command.

```
restart;
with(plots): with(plottools):
addcoords(z_cylindrical, [z, r, theta],
          [r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta), z]);

expr := Re(EllipticE(sqrt(1-r^2/(1+(1/50)*i)), sqrt(1+(1/50)*i))):

for i from 0 to 50 by 1 do
  temp := plot3d(expr,
                 r = sqrt((1/50)*i) .. sqrt(1+(1/50)*i),
                 theta = 0 .. 2*Pi, coords = z_cylindrical);
  p[i] := display(temp,
                  reflect(temp,[[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]])):
end do:

display(seq(p[i],i=sort([indices(p,nolist)])), insequence = true);
```

Another way to deal with imaginary components (being more careful about how they are discarded, based on magnitude) is to make use of the `fnormal` command instead of simply wrapping the expression in a call to `Re`.

I changed how the frames are stored, just for my own convenience. In the code above you can change the `by 1` to say `by 5` and get only one fifth as many frames but with the same end-point values for `i`.

In general you will get better performance and smaller plot structures and exported gifs if you can use `plot3d` (with coordinate system, say) than if you use `implicitplot3d`.